# Efeito Typing não fica responsivo somente com CSS

Tags: textarea, css-animations

Boa tarde galera,

Fiz, com uma ajuda de alguns colegas aqui, um efeito Typing na home, mas ele não está se tornando responsivo, não está se adaptando aos mobiles. Estou tentando também colocar de uma outra forma usando display: none; para este efeito no mobile e fazendo de outra forma, mas está resultando em um desastre.

Segue meu código, se alguém puder me iluminar, agradeço.

```css
*/ home */

/*
 * Header common styles
 */

.home-section{
    width: 100%;
    display: block;    
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center center;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}

.home-content{
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    transition-delay: 5s;
}


/* Home content */

.home-content{
    position: relative;
}
.home-text{
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    transition-delay: 4s;
}

/* Scroll down icon */

@-webkit-keyframes scroll-down-anim {
    0%{ bottom: 2px; }
    50%{ bottom: 7px; }
    100%{ bottom: 2px; }
}
@-moz-keyframes scroll-down-anim {
    0%{ bottom: 2px; }
    50%{ bottom: 7px; }
    100%{ bottom: 2px; }
}
@-o-keyframes scroll-down-anim {
    0%{ bottom: 2px; }
    50%{ bottom: 7px; }
    100%{ bottom: 2px; }
}
@keyframes scroll-down-anim {
    0%{ bottom: 2px; }
    50%{ bottom: 7px; }
    100%{ bottom: 2px; }
}

.scroll-down{
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    margin-left: -20px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    
    -webkit-transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940); 
    -moz-transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940); 
    -o-transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940); 
    transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940); 

}

.scroll-down:before{
    display: block;
    content: "";
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin: 0 0 0 -10px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    background: #fff;
    
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    
    -webkit-transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940); 
    -moz-transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940); 
    -o-transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940); 
    transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940);
    
    z-index: 1;
}

.scroll-down:hover:before{
    opacity: .6;
}


.scroll-down-icon{
    display: block;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    margin-left: -5px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 4px;
    color: #111;
    font-size: 15px;

    -webkit-animation: scroll-down-anim 1s infinite;
    -moz-animation: scroll-down-anim 1s infinite;
    -o-animation: scroll-down-anim 1s infinite;
    animation: scroll-down-anim 1s infinite; 
    
   
   z-index: 2;
}

/* Text Home */

.texto1,
.texto2 {
    font-family: "Open Sans";
    font-size: 4rem;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    animation-name: fadeIn;
    animation: texto1 7s steps(1, end) infinite;

   
}
.texto2 {
    animation: texto2 7s steps(1, end) infinite;

   

}

.fadeIn {
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeIn;
  animation-name: fadeIn;
}

div::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 0.1em;
    height: 1em;
    top: 0.2em;
    right: 0;
    opacity: 1;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }

  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}


@keyframes texto1 {
    0% {
        width: 0ch;
        opacity: 0;
    }

    33% {
        width: 30ch;
        padding-right: .2em;
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
        width: 30ch;
        padding-right: .2em;
    }
}
@keyframes texto2 {
    0% {
        width: 0ch;
        opacity: 0;
    }
    29% {
        width: 0ch;
        opacity: 0;
    }
    33% {
        width: 0ch;
        opacity: 1;
    }

    50% {
        width: 34ch;
        padding-right: .2em;

    }
    66% {
        width: 34ch;
        padding-right: .2em;
    }
    100% {
        width: 34ch;
        padding-right: .2em;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
         <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="keywords" content="">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="author" content="">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <!-- Favicons -->
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.png">

        <!-- CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/vertical-rhythm.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.carousel.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font.awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.transitions.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/simpletextrotator.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/magnific-popup.css">


           <style>
img{
    max-width:100%;
    height:auto;
}
</style>

    </head>
    <body class="appear-animate">


     <!-- BEGIN JIVOSITE CODE {literal} -->

<!-- {/literal} END JIVOSITE CODE -->
        
        <!-- Page Loader -->        
        <div class="page-loader">
            <div class="loader">Carregando...</div>
        </div>
        <!-- End Page Loader -->
        
        <!-- Page Wrap -->
        <div class="page" id="top">
            
            <!-- Home Section -->
            <section class="home-section bg-dark" data-background="video/video.jpg" id="home">
                <div class="js-height-full container">
                    
                    <!-- Video BG Init -->
                    <!-- Please, replace three video files in folder "video" with your own ones -->
                    <div class="bg-video-wrapper" id="video-background-1">
                        <div class="bg-video-overlay bg-dark-alfa-50"></div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <!-- End Video BG Init -->
                    
                    <!-- Hero Content -->
             
                    <div class="home-content">
                        <div class="home-text">
                           <h1 class="hs-line-8 font-alt mb-30 mb-xs-0">
                                <span style="background-color: #00203C">&emsp;TEXTO TEXTO TEXTO&emsp;</span>
                            </h1><br>
                            <div class="fadeIn">
                          <div class="texto1">&emsp;TEXTO TEXTO TEXTO,</div><br>
                            <div class="texto2">TEXTO TEXTO TEXTO TEXTO TEXTO TEXTO.</div>
                          </div></div></div>
                    <!-- End Hero Content -->
                    
                    <!-- Scroll Down -->
                    <div class="local-scroll">
                        <a href="#about" class="scroll-down"><i class="fa fa-angle-down scroll-down-icon"></i></a>
                    </div>
                    <!-- End Scroll Down -->
                    
                </div>
            </section>
            <!-- End Home Section -->
            </body>
            </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu código está bem confuso.... Fiz algumas mudanças nas cores apenas para ficar mais fácil de enxergar.

Na animação do `texto2` vc colocou um evento aos 50% e com isso a animação dele estava mais rápida que a animação do `texto1`, eu ajustei isso.

De resto basicamente o que vc precisa é construir os `@media` para ir ajustando o tamanho da fonte de acordo com a largura da tela. Deixei comentado no código onde vc pode arrumar isso.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o seu código corrigido.

```css
img {
   max-width: 100%;
   height: auto;
}

.home-section {
   width: 100%;
   display: block;
   position: relative;
   overflow: hidden;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-attachment: fixed;
   background-position: center center;
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
   -moz-background-size: cover;
   -o-background-size: cover;
   background-size: cover;
}

.home-content {
   display: table;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   text-align: center;
   transition-delay: 5s;
}


/* Home content */

.home-content {
   position: relative;
}

.home-text {
   display: table-cell;
   height: 100%;
   vertical-align: middle;
   transition-delay: 4s;
}

/* Scroll down icon */

@-webkit-keyframes scroll-down-anim {
   0% {
      bottom: 2px;
   }

   50% {
      bottom: 7px;
   }

   100% {
      bottom: 2px;
   }
}

@-moz-keyframes scroll-down-anim {
   0% {
      bottom: 2px;
   }

   50% {
      bottom: 7px;
   }

   100% {
      bottom: 2px;
   }
}

@-o-keyframes scroll-down-anim {
   0% {
      bottom: 2px;
   }

   50% {
      bottom: 7px;
   }

   100% {
      bottom: 2px;
   }
}

@keyframes scroll-down-anim {
   0% {
      bottom: 2px;
   }

   50% {
      bottom: 7px;
   }

   100% {
      bottom: 2px;
   }
}

.scroll-down {
   width: 40px;
   height: 40px;
   margin-left: -20px;
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 20px;
   left: 50%;
   text-align: center;
   text-decoration: none;

   -webkit-transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940);
   -moz-transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940);
   -o-transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940);
   transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940);

}

.scroll-down:before {
   display: block;
   content: "";
   width: 20px;
   height: 20px;
   margin: 0 0 0 -10px;
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 50%;
   background: #fff;

   -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
   -moz-border-radius: 2px;
   border-radius: 2px;

   -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
   -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
   -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
   -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
   transform: rotate(45deg);

   -webkit-transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940);
   -moz-transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940);
   -o-transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940);
   transition: all 500ms cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940);

   z-index: 1;
}

.scroll-down:hover:before {
   opacity: .6;
}


.scroll-down-icon {
   display: block;
   width: 10px;
   height: 10px;
   margin-left: -5px;
   position: absolute;
   left: 50%;
   bottom: 4px;
   color: #111;
   font-size: 15px;

   -webkit-animation: scroll-down-anim 1s infinite;
   -moz-animation: scroll-down-anim 1s infinite;
   -o-animation: scroll-down-anim 1s infinite;
   animation: scroll-down-anim 1s infinite;


   z-index: 2;
}

/* Text Home */

.texto1,
.texto2 {
   font-family: "Open Sans";
   font-size: 45px;
   white-space: nowrap;
   overflow: hidden;
   color: #fff;
   display: inline-block;
   position: relative;
   width: 0;
   padding-right: 0;
   animation-name: fadeIn;
   animation: texto1 7s steps(30, end) infinite;
   text-align: center;
}

.texto2 {
   animation: texto2 7s steps(36, end) infinite;
}

.fadeIn {
   -webkit-animation-name: fadeIn;
   animation-name: fadeIn;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   width: 100%;
   text-align: center;
   flex-direction: column;
}

div::after {
   content: "";
   position: absolute;
   width: 0.1em;
   height: 1em;
   top: 0.2em;
   right: 0;
   opacity: 1;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
   from {
      opacity: 0;
   }

   to {
      opacity: 1;
   }
}


@keyframes texto1 {
   0% {
      width: 0ch;
      opacity: 0;
   }

   33% {
      width: 20ch;
      padding-right: .2em;
      opacity: 1;
   }

   100% {
      width: 20ch;
      padding-right: .2em;
   }
}

@keyframes texto2 {
   0% {
      width: 0ch;
      opacity: 0;
   }

   29% {
      width: 0ch;
      opacity: 0;
   }

   33% {
      width: 0ch;
      opacity: 1;
   }

   66% {
      width: 34ch;
      padding-right: .2em;
   }

   100% {
      width: 34ch;
      padding-right: .2em;
   }
}

body {
   background-color: tomato;
}

/* aqui vc vai diminuindo o tamanho da fonte conforme precisar */
@media (max-width: 992px) {
    .texto1, .texto2 {
       font-size: 30px;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .texto1, .texto2 {
       font-size: 20px;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 480px) {
    .texto1, .texto2 {
       font-size: 12px;
    }
}
```

```html
   <!-- Page Loader -->
   <div class="page-loader">
      <div class="loader">Carregando...</div>
   </div>
   <!-- End Page Loader -->

   <!-- Page Wrap -->
   <div class="page" id="top">

      <!-- Home Section -->
      <section class="home-section bg-dark" data-background="video/video.jpg" id="home">
         <div class="js-height-full container">

            <!-- Video BG Init -->
            <!-- Please, replace three video files in folder "video" with your own ones -->
            <div class="bg-video-wrapper" id="video-background-1">
               <div class="bg-video-overlay bg-dark-alfa-50"></div>
            </div>

            <!-- End Video BG Init -->

            <!-- Hero Content -->

            <div class="home-content">
               <div class="home-text">
                  <h1 class="hs-line-8 font-alt mb-30 mb-xs-0">
                     <!-- <span style="background-color: #00203C">&emsp;TEXTO TEXTO TEXTO&emsp;</span> -->
                  </h1><br>
                  <div class="fadeIn">
                     <div class="texto1">&emsp;TEXTO TEXTO TEXTO,</div><br>
                     <div class="texto2">TEXTO TEXTO TEXTO TEXTO TEXTO TEXTO.</div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
            <!-- End Hero Content -->

            <!-- Scroll Down -->
            <div class="local-scroll">
               <a href="#about" class="scroll-down"><i class="fa fa-angle-down scroll-down-icon"></i></a>
            </div>
            <!-- End Scroll Down -->

         </div>
      </section>
   </div>
```

Comment: Salvou minha pele @hugocsl... vlw mesmo!!!!!!